# How to have multiple inputs on one line,all being passed into a method with variable arguments

Tags: java, methods

Alright,so I've got this assignment that requires me to have a method with a variable number of inputs as well as a string input. The inputs all have to be on one line in the scanner, and the method has to return the number of values entered,the average value,the max value,the min value,and the string that was entered.

This is an example of that the terminal window should look like.

```
Please enter the name of the course: CourseNameHere
Please enter the scores for CSC 201 on a single line and type a -1 at the end
71 02 81 44 84 17 38 11 20 05 93 -1

The course name     : CourseNameHere
Number of Scores    : 11
The Average Score   : 42.37
The Minimum Score   : 02
The Maximum Score   : 93
```

The Average score has to be rounded to 2 decimal places(which I think I can handle)
The only problem for me is getting the variable number of inputs to be scanned on a single line,and how to have the program count the number of inputs if I'm not hitting enter between the inputs.
This is what I have so far.but I have no idea where to go from here. I can get it to ask for sequential values,but they aren't all on the same line

```
public static int calculate(int again)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfValues = 0;
int max = -9999;
int min =  100000;
int sum = 0;
double value;

System.out.print("What is the name of the course you wish to evaluate? : ");
String courseName = input.next();
System.out.println("Please enter the scores for the class, press enter between each value." + "\n" + "Enter -1 to finish and calculate.");
for(value = 0; value != 1; numberOfValues++)
        {
            value = input.nextDouble();
            sum += value;





        }
```

Comment: What have you tried already? You need to post work and have a legitimate problem.

Comment: could you please accept an answer, or comment on the answers telling the user what is good/bad about their answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the input to the method.  Are you receiving a `String` and an array of `int`'s or a `String`, `String`.  That is, is the input from the user already broken up for you?

For example...

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String courseName = kb.nextLine();
String scoreLine = kb.nextLine();

// courseName and scoreLine now become the parameters to you method...

// You could then use another scanner to break the line down...
Scanner scoreLineScanner = new Scanner(scoreLine);

while (scoreLineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int score = scoreLineScanner.nextInt();
    if (score != -1) {
        // Calculate other values...
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I did think about using `String#split(" ")`, but then you could need to convert each element to an `int` yourself, which might or might not be suitable (it's a little more messy)

Comment: I'll try to explain it a bit better,I'm supposed to have a method that is only called when a certain variable("again" in this case) is set to 0(which it is by default). This method is supposed to take a set of scores entered by the user all on one line with spaces between them,without hitting enter.It should then calculate the Number of scores,the max,min and mean of the scores,and display all of that information
This is the method that I have so far,but im lost from here.
Edit* I have no idea how to add my code here...

Comment: Okay, so I assume you will get two `String`s, a `courseName` and a `scoreLine`.  You can use the presented idea to parse the `scoreLine` and make your calculations....

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  How to create the method?  How to parse the results? How to calculate the output? How to display the output?

Answer (score 0):

First of all with the arg[0], you will need to use substring to chop the string into a set of array variable.  Then use array.len or count to do the rest.  Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the "variable number of inputs" inputted to a `String`, use the `.split()` command on the `String` to split the `String` into parts, and assign it to an array. Then calculate the avg, max, min, etc. values with the array.

Example (tested and works perfectly):

```
String input; // assign the String to be the input

// split the input by spaces and assign every part to an element in the array
String inputArray[] = input.split(" "); 

// get the number of input numbers
double num = inputArray.length - 1; // don't include the last number, -1

double avg = 0; double max = 0; double min = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);

// get the average and min/max numbers
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++) // i < inputArray.length - 1 so you don't count the last input, which is -1
{
    avg += Double.parseDouble(inputArray[i]); // for now, set the avg to be the sum of all the numbers

    // if this input is greater than the last greatest one, set the max to be the this input
    if (Double.parseDouble(inputArray[i]) > max) {max = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[i]);}

    // if this input is lesser than the last least one, set the min to be the this input
    if (Double.parseDouble(inputArray[i]) < min) {min = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[i]);}
}
avg = avg / num; // complete the average calculation by diving by total number of inputs
avg = (double)Math.round(avg * 100) / 100; // round the average to two decimal places
```

Next, just display the values to the console: that's a simple Google search. Same with inputting the line of input.